# How to access data in AspNetUsers from .cshtml pages in ASP.NET Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm really new to ASP.NET Razor Pages. I added new fields to the AspNetUsers table and I want to display these fields in a .cshtml page. I know that to display the current user's name, I can simply do `@User.Identity.Name`.

However, I do not know how to access the other fields in the table. I tried looking online for solutions but cannot find one that's dealing with this.

Comment: Here is a discussion on related issues, you can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707589/how-do-i-display-and-update-my-custom-identity-fields-in-my-asp-net-core-applica

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of current user from `@User.Identity.Name` because, that value is in a claim from the token/cookie that you are authenticating users.

To get the rest of those Users from `AspNetUser` table, you will have to fetch the database in you controller action, and pass those values as a Model to your view

Comment: how do I do get those values as a Model? could you further elaborate?